# my react front end validation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am defining the validation in the checkbox where if it is does not checked then it should not go to the next step but i implemented the validation but it successfully go to the next step but showing the error on the checkbox icon

```
export function isValidEmployement(data) {

  const isValidOccupation = data.occupation === null || data.occupation.value === null ? false : regex.isNotEmpty.test(data.occupation);
  const isValidSourceOfIncome = data.sourcesOfIncome === null ? false : data.sourcesOfIncome
  const isValidFreelancerConsent = data.freelancerConsent;

  return {
    isValidOccupation: isValidOccupation,
    isValidSourceOfIncome: isValidSourceOfIncome,
    isValidFreelancerConsent,

    allValid:
      isValidOccupation && isValidSourceOfIncome && isValidFreelancerConsent,
  };
}
```

this is the function that will handle the validation

```
const applicantList = [...state.applicantList];
const validationResultEmployment = isValidEmployement(
   applicantList[index]
);

applicantList: [
      {
        //BASIC INFO
        fullName: "",
        purposeAccount: "",
        mobileOtp: "",
        dateOfBirth: "",
        isTaxResidentOtherThanPakistan: "",
        presentAddressConsent: false,
        permanentAddressConsent: false,
        officeCity: "",
        officeHouseNumber: "",
        officeLandmark: "",
        officeTown: "",
        officeCountry: "",
        mobileOperator: "",
        docType: "",
        docNumber: "",
        isRecapcha: false,
        selectedCardReason: "",
        factaStatus: "",
        docIssueDate: "",
        docExpiryDate: "2099-12-31",
        nationality: [],
        email: "",
        cellNo: "",
        confirmationDialogIsOpen: false,
        selectedBasicInfoPhoneNumber: {
          name: "+92",
          value: "+92",
        },
        iUnderstand: false,
        iConsent: false,
        validationResultBasicInfo: {
          isValidFullName: true,
          isValidEmail: true,
          isValidRecapcha: true,
          isValidDateOfBirth: true,
          isValidDocType: true,
          isValidDocNumber: true,
          isValidDocIssueDate: true,
          isValidDocExpiryDate: true,
          isValidCellNo: true,
          isValidIUnderstand: true,
          isValidIConsent: true,
          allValid: true,
        },

        nationalityInformation: [
          {
            nationality: "",
            passportNumber: "",
            passportExpiryDate: "",
            validationResult: {
              isValidNationality: true,
              isValidPassportNumber: true,
              isValidPassportExpiryDate: true,
              allValid: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        birthCountry: "",
        gender: "",
        motherMaidenName: "",
        fatherName: "",
        educationalLevel: "",
        isPdf: false,
        maritalStatus: "",
        residentCountry: {
          value: "Pakistan",
        },
        nationality: [],
        passportNumber: "",
        passportExpiryDate: "",
        presentHouseNumber: "",
        presentLandmark: "",
        addressType: "",
        presentTown: "",
        presentCountry: {
          value: "Pakistan",
        },
        officeCountry: {
          value: "Pakistan",
        },
        confirmationDialogIsOpen: false,
        presentCity: "",
        presentPostalCode: "",
        presentHomePhoneNo: "",
        nextOfKinpermanentAddress: "",
        permanentAddress: "",
        permanentHouseNumber: "",
        permanentLandmark: "",
        presentResidenceHomePhoneCountryCode: "",
        incomeTaxConsent: false,

        //Consent info
        adaAndAdraConsent: false,
        freelancerConsent: false,

        permanentTown: "",
        permanentCountry: {
          value: "Pakistan",
        },
        permanentCity: "",
        permanentPostalCode: "",
        permanentHomePhoneNo: "",
        permanentPhoneCode: {
          value: "+92",
        },
        presentPhoneCode: {
          value: "+92",
        },
        showAddNewAddressTextBox: true,
        validationNationalityResult: {
          isValidNationality: true,
          isValidPassportNumber: true,
          isValidPassportExpiryDate: true,
        },
        validationResultCustomerinfo: {
          isValidBirthCountry: true,
          isValidGender: true,
          isValidNationality: true,
          isValidMotherMaidenName: true,
          isValidFatherName: true,
          isValidEducationalLevel: true,
          isValidMaritalStatus: true,
          isValidResidentCountry: true,
          isValidPresentHouseNumber: true,
          isValidPresentLandmark: true,
          isValidPresentTown: true,
          isValidPresentCountry: true,
          isValidPresentCity: true,
          isValidPresentPostalCode: true,
          isValidPresentHomePhoneNo: true,
          isValidPermanentAddress: true,
          isValidPermanentHouseNumber: true,
          isValidPermanentLandmark: true,
          isValidPermanentTown: true,
          isValidPermanentCountry: true,
          isValidPermanentCity: true,
          isValidPermanentPostalCode: true,
          isValidDateOfBirth: true,
          isValidDocIssueDate: true,
          isValidDocExpiryDate: true,
          isValidPermanentHomePhoneNo: true,
          isValidCorrespondenceAddress: true,
          isValidOfficeHouseNumber: true,
          isValidOfficeLandMarkError: true,
          isValidOfficeTown: true,
          isValidOfficeCountry: true,
          isValidOfficeError: true,
        },
        rowAdded: true,

        //NEXT OF KIN INFO

        kinName: "",
        kinRelation: "",
        kinContactNo: "",
        kinId: "",
        nextKinAddress: "",
        selectedKinPhoneNumber: "",
        kinHouseNumber: "",
        kinLandmark: "",
        kinTown: "",
        kinCountry: "",
        kinCity: "",
        kinPermanentAddress: "",
        kinPostalCode: "",
        kinHomePhoneNo: "",
        kinConfirmationDialogIsOpen: false,
        kinSelectedLandLinePhoneNumber: "",
        validationResultNextOfKin: {
          isValidKinName: true,
          isValidKinRelation: true,
          isValidKinContactNo: true,
          isValidKinId: true,
          isValidNextKinAddress: true,
          isValidHouseNumber: true,
          isValidLandmark: true,
          isValidTown: true,
          isValidCountry: true,
          isValidCity: true,
          isValidPostalCode: true,
          isValidHomePhoneNo: true,
        },

        //EMPLOYMENT INFO

        occupation: "",
        validationResultEmployment: {
          isValidOccupation: true,
          isValidSourceOfIncome: true,
          isValidFreelancerConsent: true
        },
        sourcesOfIncome: [],
        validationResultFund: {
          isValidAddress: true,
          isValidCity: true,
          isValidCountry: true,
          isValidEmployerOrBusinessName: true,
          isValidEmploymentType: true,
          isValidHomePhone: true,
          isValidHomePhoneCountryCode: true,
          isValidLegalIdNo: true,
          isValidNearestLandmark: true,
          isValidContactNumber: true,
          isValidOfficePhone: true,
          isValidOfficePhoneCountryCode: true,
          isValidPostalCode: true,
          isValidRelationship: true,
          isValidTownTehsil: true,
          isValidFundProviderConsent: true,
        },
        isValidEmploymentBusinessAddress: {
          isValidAddress: true,
          isValidNearestLandmark: true,
          isValidTownTehsil: true,
        },

        //FACTA INFO
        usPerson: "",
        usConnections: "",
        countryOfTaxResidency: "",
        taxIdentificationNumber: "",
        confirmationDialogIsOpen: false,
        tinReason: "",
        tinReasonIfBSelect: "",
        countryTaxInfoList: [
          {
            countryOfTaxResidency: "",
            taxIdentificationNumber: "",
            tinReason: "",
            tinReasonIfBSelect: "",
            validationResult: {
              isValidCountryOfTaxResidency: true,
              isValidTaxIdentificationNumber: true,
              isValidTinReason: true,
              isValidTinReasonIfB: true,
              allValid: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        validationResultFactaInfo: {
          isValidCountryInfoList: true,
          isValidUsConnections: true,
          isValidUsPerson: true,
        },
        isValidCountryInfoList: {
          isValidcountryOfTaxResidency: true,
          isValidTaxIdentificationNumber: true,
          isValidTinReason: true,
          isValidTinReasonIfB: true,
        },
        validationResultIncomeAndTax: {
          isValidOccupation: true,
          isValidSourceOfIncome: true,
          isValidFactaStatus: true,
          isValidZakatExemption: true,
          isValidFiqqah: true,
          isValidZakatExemptionsConsent: true,
          isValidIncometaxConsent: true,
          isValidTaxResidentOtherThanPakistan: true,
        },

        // Employer Business Detail Info
        employerBusinessName: "",
        employerBusinessAddress: "",

        //ACCOUNT INFORMATION SUBMIT
        eftConsent: false,
        submitButtoClicked: false,
        addAnotherAccountDialog: false,
        debitCardList: [
          {
            debitCardType: {
              value: "CARD_TYPE_SONERI_PAYPAK",
            },
            debitCardName: "",
            validationResult: {
              isValidDebitCardType: true,
              isValidDebitCardName: true,
              allValid: true,
            },
          },
          {
            debitCardType: {
              value: "CARD_TYPE_SONERI_PAYPAK",
            },
            debitCardName: "",
            validationResult: {
              isValidDebitCardType: true,
              isValidDebitCardName: true,
              allValid: true,
            },
          },
          {
            debitCardType: {
              value: "CARD_TYPE_SONERI_PAYPAK",
            },
            debitCardName: "",
            validationResult: {
              isValidDebitCardType: true,
              isValidDebitCardName: true,
              allValid: true,
            },
          },
          {
            debitCardType: {
              value: "CARD_TYPE_SONERI_PAYPAK",
            },
            debitCardName: "",
            validationResult: {
              isValidDebitCardType: true,
              isValidDebitCardName: true,
              allValid: true,
            },
          },
        ],
        bankAccountDetails: [
          {
            foreignBankName: "",
            accountNumber: "",
          },
        ],
        natureOfCashWithDraw: [],
        raastRegistration: "",
        smsAlertActivation: "",
        smsAlertActivationConsent: false,
        electronicFundTransfer: "",

        accountTypeState: account && account.get("productType"),
        accountProductId: account && account.get("productId"),
        foreignRemittances: false,
        fundsTransfer: false,
        outwardClearing: false,
        annualIncome: "",
        monthlyCreditTRansactions: "",
        monthlyDebitTransactions: "",
        monthlyCredit: "",
        monthlyDebit: "",
        foreignBankName: "",
        accountNumber: "",
        // correspondenceAddress: "",
        correspondenceAddress: "",
        correspondenceNearestLandmark: "",
        correspondenceTownTehsil: "",
        correspondenceCountry: "",
        correspondenceCity: "",
        correspondencePostalCode: "",
        correspondenceHomePhone: "",
        correspondenceHomePhoneCountryCode: "",
        eStatementSubscriptionConsent: false,
        chequebook: "",
        chequebookLeaves: "",
        chequebookLabel: "",
        chequebookLabel2: false,
        successDialogIsOpen: false,
        debitCard: "",
        debitCardType: "",
        debitCardLabel: "",
        electronicFundTransfer: "",
        electronicFundTransferLabel: "",
        eStatementSubscription: [],
        zakatExemptions: "",
        fiqqah: "",
        desiredBranch: "",
        zakatExemptionsConsent: false,
        selectedProvince: "",
        selectedCity: "",
        isEStatementSubscription: "",
        staffReferal: "",
        annualIncomeAmountEstimateRanges: "",
        monthlyAccountCreditAmountEstimateRanges: "",
        monthlyAccountCreditCountEstimateRanges: "",
        monthlyAccountDebitAmountEstimateRanges: "",
        monthlyAccountDebitCountEstimateRanges: "",
        validationBankAccountsResult: {
          isValidForeignBankName: true,
          isValidAccountNumber: true,
        },
        validationResultAccount: {
          isValidCashWithdrawl: true,
          isValidZakatExemptionDropdown: true,
          isValidBankAccountDetails: true,
          isValidForeignRemittances: true,
          isValidChequeBookConsent2: true,
          isValidFundsTransfer: true,
          isValidOutwardClearing: true,
          isValidEStatementSubscriptionConsent: true,
          isValidMonthlyAccountDebitCountEstimateRanges: true,
          isValidRaastRegistration: true,
          isValidSmsAlertActivationConsent: true,
          isValidSmsAlertActivation: true,
          isValidCorrespondenceAddress: true,
          isValidHouseNumber: true,
          isValidLandmark: true,
          isValidTown: true,
          isValidCountry: true,
          isValidCity: true,
          isValidPostalCode: true,
          isValidHomePhoneNo: true,
          isValidChequebook: true,
          isValidChequebookLeaves: true,
          isValidDebitCard: true,
          isValidDebitCardType: true,
          isValidElectronicFundTransfer: true,
          isValidEStatementSubscription: true,
          isValidZakatExemptions: true,
          isValidFiqqah: true,
          isValidDesiredBranch: true,
          isValidStaffReferal: true,
          isValidZakatExemption: true,
          isValidAnnualIncome: true,

          monthlyAccountCreditAmountEstimateRanges: true,
          isValidMonthlyDebit: true,
          isValidMonthlyAccountCreditCountEstimateRanges: true,
          isValidMonthlyCredit: true,
          isValidForeignBankAccountDetails: true,
          isValidDebitCardConsent: true,
          isValidChequeBookConsent: true,
          isValidElectronicTransferConsent: true,
          isValidZakatExemptionConsent: true,
          isValidPurposeAccount: true,
          isValidDebitCardReason: true,
          isValidIsEStatementSubscription: true,
          isValidEftConsent: true,
        },

        validationResultSingleAccount: {
          isValidAnnualIncome: true,
          isValidBankAccountDetails: true,
          isValidZakatExemption: true,
          isValidZakatExemptionConsent: true,
        },
        rowAddedAccount: true,

        //DOCUMENTS

        occupation: "",
        selectedValue: "",
        imagePreviewDialogIsOpen: false,
        termsAndConditionDialogIsClicked: false,
        disclaimersClicked: false,
        showDisclaimersError: false,
        livePictureDialogIsOpen: false,
        confirmationDialogIsOpen: false,
        submitButtonIsClicked: false,
        showTermsAndConditionError: false,
        showKFSError: false,
        errorDialogIsOpen: false,
        employerBusinessName: "",
        successDialogIsOpen: false,
        houseNumber: "",
        landmark: "",
        town: "",
        country: "",
        city: "",
        postalCode: "",
        homePhoneNo: "",
        signature: false,
        validationResultConsentAndDeclaration: {
          isValidDisclaimers: true,
          isValidTermsAndConditions: true,
          isValidUndertakingOfPersonalFunds: true,
        },
        validationResultDocuments: {
          isValidSignature: true,
        },
        termsAndConditions: false,
        disclaimers: false,
        undertakingOfPersonalFunds: false,
        KfsClicked: false,
        invalidType: [],
      },
    ],
```

In validationResultEmployment i called the function isValidEmployement
this is my applicantList array inside the state

```
 <Employement
redirectTo={redirectTo}
execStatusGetConfigurations={execStatusGetConfigurations}
validationCheck={validationCheck}
handleTaxesOfInformation={handleTaxesOfInformation}
handleChange={handleChange}
productId={account && account.get("productId")}
execStatusAddFactaCrsInfo={execStatusSaveApplication}
handleFactaRow={handleFactaRow}
handleAccountChange={handleAccountChange}
handleSourceOfIncomeValueChange={handleSourceOfIncomeValueChange}
initialSourceOfIncome={initialSourceOfIncome}
handleTaxesOfInformationSelect={handleTaxesOfInformationSelect}
onConsentChange={onConsentChange}
goBack={goBack}
{...props}
{...state.applicantList[currentActiveStep]}
validationResultFund={{
...state.applicantList[currentActiveStep].validationResultFund,
 }}
validationResultEmployment={{
   ...state.applicantList[currentActiveStep]
  .validationResultEmployment,
 }}
  validationResult={{
...state.applicantList[currentActiveStep]
.validationResultIncomeAndTax,
              }}
            />
```

I am passing the validationResultEmployment to the employment comp as a prop

```
isValid={
 props.validationResultEmployment.isValidFreelancerConsent ===
 false
? false
: true
 }
```

and this is i am checking if it is valid but it does not work

I am trying to get the similar implementation but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

you can test it:

```html
export function isValidEmployement(employeeId, data) {
  const isValidOccupation =
    data.occupation === null || data.occupation.value === null
      ? false
      : regex.isNotEmpty.test(data.occupation);
  const isValidSourceOfIncome =
    data.sourcesOfIncome === null ? false : data.sourcesOfIncome;
  const isValidFreelancerConsent = !!data.freelancerConsent;
  const allValid =
    isValidOccupation && isValidSourceOfIncome && isValidFreelancerConsent;
  setState((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    applicantList: {
      ...prev.applicantList,
      validationResultEmployment: {
        isValidOccupation,
        isValidSourceOfIncome,
        isValidFreelancerConsent,
      },
    },
  }));
}

<Employement
  //...
  validationResultEmployment={{
    ...state.applicantList[currentActiveStep].validationResultEmployment,
  }}
/>;
```